# Android pm install from terminal takes forever and does nothing

Tags: android, shell, terminal, installation, apk

When I run

```
su
pm install -r /sdcard/my.apk
    pkg: /sdcard/my.apk
```

it keep stuck foverer and does nothing (occurs with any app).

logcat:

```
    -------- beginning of system
    E/ActivityManager( 4392): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
    --------- beginning of main
    E/MPlugin (19178): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
    D/InternationalCompat(19178): applicationiInit chinese build
E/ActivityManager( 4392): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
    I/TmBinderCacher(19178): onServiceConnected name=ComponentInfo{com.miui.securitycenter/com.miui.networkassistant.service.tm.TrafficManageService}
    E/JavaBinder(19178): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

and this when kill the process:

```
W/InputEventReceiver( 6032): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
F/libc    ( 8543): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE), code 0 in tid 8543 (su)
E/AEE/AED ( 8591): ptrace attach failed: Permission denied
```

I did can install apk before (hours before I did).

I'm doing this from device (terminal emulator)... is as if package manager was broken because many installs at time and some was interrumped... any way to fix package manager?

I have got unknown source, root, blah blah blah... I try reboot, clear dalvik-cache, reflash ROM, etc... if I will wipe data sure that the problem will be fixed, but I don't want wipe data...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change some of your developer options that allow you to install APK file over USB to your internal storage or added SD Card.

1. First make sure you have developer options enabled. If you need to do so, open settings, scroll down to "about device" and tap on this 7 times.

2) In settings, click on Additional Settings

3) Click on Developer Options

4) Click toggle of "Install via USB" to enable it.  Go on to step 5 below even if you do not see "Install via USB" as an option

5) Turn on "USB debugging" in developer options as well

That's my best guess.

Comment: I'm doing this from device (terminal emulator)... is as if package manager was broken because many installs at time and some was interrumped... any way to fix package manager?